# URL Binding issue Vue/webpack

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

I'm having a peculiar problem when I'm trying to bind an img-tag to a dynamic url.

After finding some similar solutions I found the way to go was by binding the src attribute like this 
`:src="require(....)"`

The problem is however that it only works in the specific format
`:src="require('@assets/vendor-'+name+'.svg')"`

I'd like to use format `src:="require(path)"` but I can't seem to get this solution to work.
After some reading some suggestions would point to Webpack causing the issue but currently my knowledge is very limited.

EDIT 1:
Currently I have to extract  the name from the JSON-file and add it to that path rather than just using the path found in the JSON-file.

`:src="require('@/assets/vendor-' + this.$store.state.vendors[this.cardInfo.vendor].name + '.svg')"`

I'd like to make this work

`:src="require(this.$store.state.vendors[this.cardInfo.vendor].baseUrl)"`

Comment: You should put all your assets inside the `/public` folder in your project - and then simply use absolute paths in `src` without `require`.

Comment: can you add one example that not work in your case

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thank you, I did put the assets in the public-folder and somehow I was able to reference them just by file-name without the path. Cheers!